# Github: can I see my activity per day?

Tags: github

At the end of the day I need to fill my timesheet and I forget what I did all day, [Github Profile](https://github.com/vitaly-zdanevich) page do not show activity per day

Answer (score 2):

Click those green tiles one by one, the activity at the bottom will reveal what are those:[image: github dark contributions green squares]

Comment: That sad moment when you click it and see that you didn't really do anything substantial the whole day 